# Executing Update script only if all checks are done

Tags: php, database, forms, comparison-operators

I have an update script that updates username, password, telephone,usergenerated id etc.  So lets say a user decides to change his/her telephone but not the username.  But when they go to edit their information, all of the above mentioned fields are present on the form.  So the also get submitted along with what the user wants to have changed.  So i am using the code below to detect that.  So if the username in the field matches the username pulled from the session, it means its ok to continue, if not then print that the username is already taken.  But the issue is that i have to run this query twice, once for the username and once for the unique id by the user.  Further it gets complicated when the Update script is at the bottomo of the page.  The codes below will detect it but they would stop at echo.  So how do i make it so the code checks for those conditions and then upon successful completion it points to the update query.

Check 1:

```
if ($username == $_POST['username') {
  echo "Good to go";
} else {
  echo "already in use";
}
```

Check 2:

```
if ($usergenid == $_POST['usergenid') {
  echo "Good to go";
} else {
  echo "already in use";
}
```

Comment: can you rephrase that, read it twice and have no idea what your actully asking.

Comment: can i do something like this:   if ($postedusername == $dbusername) {
else  {
($postedid == $dbid) 

} else {
} else {
   echo "already in use";
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe i'm misunderstanding the question, but can you nest your conditions?

Original

```
$result = null;

if($username == $_POST['username']) 
{
   if($usergenid == $_POST['usergenid'])
   {

      /* perform update to user */
      $sql = 'UPDATE users SET username = ' . $_POST['username'] . ' WHERE id = ' . $_POST['usergenid'];
      if(mysql_query($sql))
      {
         $result = 'User updated';
      }
      else
      { 
         $result = 'Update failed';
      }

   }
   else
   {
      $result = 'User id already in use';
   }
} 
else 
{
  $result = 'Username already in use';
}

return $result;
```

Update username if user_id matches

```
$result = null;

if($usergenid == $_POST['usergenid'])
{
   if($username != $_POST['username']) 
   {

      /* perform update to user */
      $sql = 'UPDATE users SET username = ' . $_POST['username'] . ' WHERE id = ' . $_POST['usergenid'];
      if(mysql_query($sql))
      {
         $result = 'username updated';
      }
      else
      { 
         $result = 'update failed';
      }

   }
   else
   {
      $result = 'username is the same, no update performed';
   }
} 
else 
{
  $result = 'user id does not match';
}

return $result;
```

Comment: Great.  That is partly what i am looking for.  Now.  If both terms are satisfied how can i execute the mysql update command? Because if the response is good to go, i want it to directly update the script.  If the response is already in use i wan thtem to fix it and then hit submit again and then if its right it should go through.

Comment: Is there a way i can do that? If the answer is good to go, can i execute an sql query instead of echoing? And i guess the query will keep repeating until they are good to go...?

Comment: i've updated the code example, since you've 'drilled' down to where those two conditions are satisfied you can just put your updates within that condition... it's not the best example since i'm not exactly sure of the scenario, but i hope this at least helps in terms of narrowing down conditions and making an update and returning some result of how far your code went. you'll of course want to cleanse your update data instead of using $_POST directly

Comment: note that this code as it is doesn't change anything about the user, since it's updating the user with two values that haven't changed. if you are trying to let a user update their username then you'll check if the user ids match, then if the usernames do not match then you would write your username update query, so the example is a little funky in that regard, but the process the same. i'll add that scenario in addition...